# How to answer this question in a job interview

Tags: professionalism, interviewing

I'm recently graduated and I'm actually unemployed from a short term project which lasted a few months, i don't have the one year of experiencie required and this question always gets me nervous,

"*Why this company should be interested in hiring you?*" 
or 
"*What do you think you could contribute to this company?*"

What's the best I answer I could give?

Comment: What answer do you normally give? What do you *think* you should say?

Comment: i always say something like "even my experience is from a few months i'm think i'm capable to do this job "

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ideally, you would know something about the work done at the company, and would have given some thought as to how your current skills and ambitions could be used to help them. Are you a problem-solver? Are you a social gatherer (definitely a plus for companies where collaboration is important)? Do you have energy and passion for the type of work they do (every *says* they do, can you *demonstrate* that you do based on past experiences you can relate)?

Comment: So i should highlight skills over experience , alright

Comment: I interview software developers, specifically, and we look for skills, experience, and **_attitude_**. You could highlight things you have done in the past in other work assignments, in volunteer work, and in classes in which you excelled and which you really enjoyed. Being a recent graduate, it's understandable that you might have less experience and skill, but your attitude (willingness, drive to learn/accomplish, work well with others and under pressure, etc.) will help them see you as someone worth training up in their ways.

Answer (score 0):

> "Why this company should be interested in hiring you?" or "What do you
>   think you could contribute to this company?"
>
> What's the best i answer i could give?

Generally this is where I tend to mix my knowledge of the company with my own skills. Am I helping the company be more efficient, scale up their systems, fix issues in their systems, etc.? Part of this is about knowing the work at a high level, what does the company need, and what can I bring to the table.

I'd consider what kinds of results could I bring that would shape my answer here. There can be something to be said for *how* you answer rather than the details here. Are you confident of what you do? Are you ready to get stuff done?